# Reverse vowels in a string using nested for loops

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have a program to reverse the vowels in a string. I've seen many solutions however none of them are solutions with nested for loops. Is it possible to implement nested for loops into my code (which works), and if so, how would I code this? Thanks

```
def reverse_vowels(word):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    string = list(word)
    i = 0
    j = len(word)-1

    while i < j:
        if string[i].lower() not in vowels:
            i += 1
        elif string[j].lower() not in vowels:
            j -= 1
        else:
            string[i], string[j] = string[j], string[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    return "".join(string)

string = input("Enter string: ")
print(reverse_vowels(string))
```

Comment: This is not a candidate for nested for loops.  Why would you want to?  Each problem has a "target" algorithm.

Comment: The problem doesn't require nested loops? You have a single item to loop over (the word to be reversed) so only require one loop (not a loop within a loop as "nested" implies), trying to force a nested loop in here makes no sense?

Comment: Yeah I thought it would perhaps be possible, but now I understand why it's not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. The answer does not involve nested loops, but has two sequential for loops.

```
def reverse(word, ref_vowels='aeiouAEIOU'):

   #  hello Hank Hill --> hilla Honk Hell

   vowels = []

   ll = 0
   for letter in word:
      if letter in ref_vowels:
         vowels.append(word[ll])

      ll += 1

   revword = ''
   ll = 0
   ii = 0
   for letter in word:
      if letter in vowels:
         revword += vowels[-1 - ii]
         ii += 1
      else:
         revword += word[ll]
      ll += 1
    
   return revword

print(reverse('Hello Hank Hill'))
```